# Pass intent to my fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, nfc

I have implemented the **NFC foreground dispatch** in my **Activity**. The code works fine, when the NFC tag get close to my phone, the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` is called.

Now, I would like to show an **Fragment**(MyFragment.java) when the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` is invoked. There is `resolveIntent(Intent intent)` method defined in the **Fragment** class.

Here is some code of my **Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   …
   @Override
   public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

      //How to pass the 'intent' to MyFragment?
      MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeholder, fragment, fragmentName);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
   }        
}
```

Code of **MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
    …
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
       ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
      super.onResume();

       //How to get 'intent' here 
       resolveIntent(intent);
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent){
       ...
    }
}
```

My question is how could I pass the `intent` from `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` to **MyFragment** so that I can handle the intent in **MyFragment** in `onResume()`?

Comment: Take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456873/handling-onnewintent-in-fragment . I am not sure if this will satisfy your need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that Intent is an parcelable object, I can use bundle.putParcelable() method to pass the intent instance to the next fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the intent in a field in your activity. Add a method like getLastIntent() and the call it in your fragment with getActivity().getLastIntent().

Or Extrat info from the intent and create a Bundle that you will use with fragment.setArguments() and in the onStart() method of your fragment use getArguments()

Comment: I have also came up with the idea of using bundle. But how can I put intent instance input a bundle?

Comment: You know intent contains data you will read. To retive everythings: getExtras() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras())